# Inject Signed Operation Fails With Unrevealed_Key Error

Tags: operation, eztz

I've learned a lot today, and I couldn't have gotten this far so quickly without this StackExchange. I've almost got sending worked out, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this is failing at the point of injection with a "unrevealed_key" error.

I am aware that I should decode the forged transaction and reverify the values to ensure the remote node hasn't tried to change my transaction, but I removed that bit from this post for the sake of simplicity.

```
const send = (from, to, amount, sk) => {

sotez.rpc.getHead()
    .then(head => {
        const operation = {
            branch: head.hash,
            contents: [{
                kind: 'transaction',
                source: from,
                fee: '50000',
                counter: '31204',
                gas_limit: '10200',
                storage_limit: '0',
                amount: amount,
                destination: to,
            }],
        }

        sotez.tezos.forge(head, operation)
            .then(unsigned => {
                const binary = unsigned.opbytes

                sotez.crypto.sign(binary, sk, '0x03')
                    .then(signed => {
                        operation.signature = signed.edsig

                        sotez.rpc.inject(operation, signed.sbytes)
                            .then(result => {
                                console.log(result)
                            })
                    })
            })
    })
}

send('tz1htPf3VPXrHBTX1E7y3tBteib6hA9Teosj', 'tz3WXYtyDUNL91qfiCJtVUX746QpNv5i5ve5', '1000000', 'edskS6KrT1G365PsuQiMVvPgZCS1CKTC5EFc7N...')
```

Returns: `[{"kind":"branch","id":"proto.003-PsddFKi3.contract.unrevealed_key","contract":"tz1htPf3VPXrHBTX1E7y3tBteib6hA9Teosj"}]`

Edit:
So I need to reveal this account first. I modified my send method to check if the account has been revealed before, and if not then add the revealing to the list of operations. Now I get `{"kind":"permanent","id":"proto.003-PsddFKi3.operation.invalid_signature"}`.

```
const send = (from, to, amount, keys, revealed) => {

tezos.rpc.getHead()
    .then(head => {
        const operation = {
            branch: head.hash,
            contents: [{
                kind: 'transaction',
                source: from,
                fee: '50000',
                counter: '31205',
                gas_limit: '10200',
                storage_limit: '0',
                amount: amount,
                destination: to
            }],
        }

        if (!revealed) {
            operation.contents.unshift({
                kind: 'reveal',
                fee: '1269',
                counter: '31204',
                public_key: keys.pk,
                source: from,
                gas_limit: '10000',
                storage_limit: '0',
            })
        }

        tezos.tezos.forge(head, operation)
            .then(unsigned => {
                const binary = unsigned.opbytes

                tezos.crypto.sign(binary, keys.sk, '0x03')
                    .then(signed => {
                        operation.signature = signed.edsig

                        tezos.rpc.inject(operation, signed.sbytes)
                            .then(result => {
                                console.log(result)
                            })
                    })
            })
    })
}

send('tz1htPf3VPXrHBTX1E7y3tBteib6hA9Teosj', 'tz3WXYtyDUNL91qfiCJtVUX746QpNv5i5ve5', '1000000', keys, false)
```

Edit2:
This worked, using sendOperation

```
const send = (from, to, amount, keys) => {

sotez.rpc.getHead()
    .then(head => {
        const operation = {
                kind: 'transaction',
                source: from,
                fee: '50000',
                gas_limit: '10200',
                storage_limit: '0',
                amount: amount,
                destination: to
        }

        const params = {
            from,
            operation,
            keys
        }

        sotez.rpc.sendOperation({from, operation, keys})
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
            })
    })
}

send('tz1htPf3VPXrHBTX1E7y3tBteib6hA9Teosj', 'tz3WXYtyDUNL91qfiCJtVUX746QpNv5i5ve5', '1000000', keys)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before sending transactions from an account, a 'reveal' operation must be made for the account. It looks like this account may have been activated, but not yet revealed. To make this work we would need to include the reveal operation in the list of operations:

```
sotez.rpc.getHead()
  .then(head => {
    const operation = {
      branch: head.hash,
      contents: [
        {
          kind: 'reveal',
          fee: '1269',
          counter: '31204',
          public_key: keys.pk,
          source: from,
          gas_limit: '10000',
          storage_limit: '0',
        },
        {
          kind: 'transaction',
          source: from,
          fee: '50000',
          counter: '31205',
          gas_limit: '10200',
          storage_limit: '0',
          amount: amount,
          destination: to,
        }
      ],
    }
    ...
  })
```

After the account has been revealed, the reveal is not needed to be included in the operations thereafter.

SendOperation Answer:

```
const send = (from, to, amount, keys) => {
  const operation = {
    kind: 'transaction',
    source: from,
    fee: '50000',
    gas_limit: '10200',
    storage_limit: '0',
    amount: `${amount}`,
    destination: to,
  };

  rpc.sendOperation({ from, operation, keys })
    .then(result => console.log(result));
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question with the reveal operation added. When I run it now, it just hangs with no result or error.

Comment: Ah nevermind, it was because of the counter increment. I noticed your edit and fixed it in my method. Oddly, though, now I'm getting this error: {"kind":"permanent","id":"proto.003-PsddFKi3.operation.invalid_signature"}

Comment: Have you tried the same transfer using rpc.sendOperation? sendOperation should handle whether the transaction needs a reveal and all the counters for the operations.

Comment: I tried that method first, and it just hung with no response or error. Then I thought I would do it this way, thinking it would be more secure, as I didn't like that the sendOperation takes the keys object as a parameter, and I was hoping to build this app without hosting my own node. But now that I've gone through and written it this way, I realized that I am still sending the pk and sk anyhow within the operation... so that's not good! But to answer your question, I did try that, and it just hung.

Comment: I'll have to see what is making the responses hang, bit I think I tried one of your examples from earlier and noticed that the amount key wasn't being handled correctly in sotez (was supposed to be coerced into a string). If you try your sendOperation and make the amount a string, as well as adding a fee, gas_limit, and storage_limit that may work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! I've updated my question to use sendOperation. This time it's not hanging, it's returning "TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined"

Comment: I just remembered that sendOperation takes a params object containing the from, the operation, and the keys. I've updated my question, and it worked!